# SImple way to get stock camera images location in Android /DCIM/?

Tags: android, camera, stock

I have an idea for an app, and to do it i need to be in the folder where the stock camera stores it's pictures. But since most manufactureres name the folder inside DCIM diferently, is there a way to find the specific folder that the camera saves pictures into. Also I can't list and open the first result because, for example i have 5 folders in there. Thanks!

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47515421/966789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i ended up doing it with .exists()

```
String abcd = "is it working ?";
          File pathimg = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
          File testimg = new File (pathimg, "100MEDIA/");
          if (testimg.exists()){abcd = testimg.toString();}
          else {
              File testimg2 = new File (pathimg, "100ANDRO/");
              if (testimg2.exists()){abcd = testimg2.toString();}
              else {
                  File testimg3 = new File (pathimg, "Camera/");
                  if (testimg3.exists()){abcd = testimg3.toString();}
                  else {
                      File testimg4 = new File (pathimg, "100LGDSC/");
                      if (testimg4.exists()){abcd = testimg4.toString();}
                      else {
                          abcd = "It's not working";
                      }
                  }                   
              }
          }
```

On my G2 with the folder "100LGDSC" it's working.

Comment: If you find out that there are more dirnames alternatives, it would be more convenient to iterate through an array of possible dirnames and break when one of them exists().

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution is to insert photo to MediaStore using ContentResolver (it will create empty JPG file), retrieve its path and delete it from MediaStore (file will be deleted as well).

```
public static File getPhotoDirPath(ContentResolver cr)
{
    try
    {
        Uri takenPhotoUri=cr.insert( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues( 1 ) );
        if ( takenPhotoUri == null )
            return null;
        String photoFilePath=null;
        Cursor cursor = cr.query( takenPhotoUri, new String[] { MediaColumns.DATA }, null, null, null );
        if ( cursor != null )
        {
            int dataIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex( MediaColumns.DATA );
            if (dataIdx>=0&&cursor.moveToFirst())
                photoFilePath = cursor.getString( dataIdx );
            cursor.close();
        }
        cr.delete( takenPhotoUri, null, null );
        if (photoFilePath!=null)
            return new File(photoFilePath).getParentFile();
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {//insert or delete failed
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that in some cases (the same as when camera apps are not able to save photos) photos may not be inserted successfully eg. SD card is removed (if device cannot emulate external storage), external storage is mounted read-only or some directory in path is write protected etc.

Answer (score 0):

you may take [Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_PICTURES)  as the valid directory.

The following will refer to that directory (but it is not guaranteed in all devices):

```
File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Comment: So this gives me /SDCard/Pictures. There is .DIRECTORY_DCIM but that goes into the DCIM and that's all. I need it to go one level deeper but there might not be an eazy wey.